# ReplicaSet MongoDB

Tags: replication, mongodb, nosql

I'am trying to create replcaSet in MongoDB and I'am facing a problem.

This is what I did step by step:

1- I entered this command to create these repertories:

```
mkdir \data\rs1 \data\rs2 \data\rs3
```

2- I entered this:

```
start mongod --replSet amir --logpath \data\rs1\1.log --dbpath \data\rs1 --port 27017 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64
```

As a second  cmd:

```
start mongod --replSet amir --logpath \data\rs1\2.log --dbpath \data\rs2 --port 27018 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64
```

Then as a third cmd:

```
start mongod --replSet amir --logpath \data\rs1\3.log --dbpath \data\rs3 --port 27019 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64
```

After that I entered this in the first cmd:

```
config={_id:"amir", members:[ {_id:0,host:"localhost:27017"},  {_id:1,host:"localhost:27018"}, 
{_id:2,host:"localhost:27019"}] };
```

And finnally I entered:

```
 rs.initiate (config);
```

It showed me this :

```
  { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Missing expected field \"version\"", "code" : 93 }
```

Do you have any ideas on this problem?

[image]

Comment: What makes it so hard to [follow the tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, and the reason was connected than mongo was using my  pc name instead of localhost..

start mongoD and search for this string:

> 2016-03-07T16:01:05.777+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=26176 port=27017 dbpath=G:\data\db\ 64-bit **host=MyLaptop**

So I had to switch from **localhost** to **mylaptop** in config

please valid form of config

```
var config={_id:"amir", 
                "version" : 1,
                members:[ {_id:0,host:"localhost:27017"},  
                {_id:1,host:"localhost:27018"}, 
                {_id:2,host:"localhost:27019"}] };
```

Comment: +1 I can attest that MongoDB (on linux at least) is picky about FQDNs.

Comment: @AliRazeghi It is not picky. Names just must be resolvable. You can even use `/etc/hosts` and pick funky names. And they don't need to be FQDNs.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg man I've had bad experiences in earlier versions and in Hadoop both.  I'll test out the post 2.4 versions though, maybe by 3.2 my experiences would be nullified.

Answer (score 0):

This [rs.initiate() command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/) failed because you missed out the *version* field from the supplied config.

Your error message made that reasonably clear:

> { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Missing expected field \"version\"", "code" : 93 }

The [*version*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.version) field is mandatory in the replica set configuration; you can see it is included in the examples in the doc page on the [rs.initiate command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/), the doc page on the [configuration document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/), and the doc page giving a [basic tutorial on deploying a replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/).